# Is there a reason for so many react vulnerabilities on a brand new 17.0.2 project?

Tags: reactjs, npm

So im doing a react project with some colleages and i got
"found 87 vulnerabilities (82 moderate, 5 high)"
Now i done audit fix that outputed:

```
browserslist  4.0.0 - 4.16.4
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/browserslist
  react-dev-utils  >=6.0.0-next.03604a46
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

css-what  <5.0.1
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/css-what
  css-select  <=3.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of css-what
  node_modules/css-select
    svgo  >=1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  >=4.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
      postcss-svgo  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
      Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/postcss-svgo

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: moderate
Regular expression denial of service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
        webpack  4.44.0 - 4.46.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
        node_modules/webpack
          react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
    webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.11.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server

normalize-url  <=4.5.0 || 5.0.0 - 5.3.0 || 6.0.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/normalize-url
node_modules/postcss-normalize-url/node_modules/normalize-url
  humanize-url  <=1.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
  node_modules/humanize-url
    filenamify-url  1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of humanize-url
    node_modules/filenamify-url
      gh-pages  >=1.2.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of filenamify-url
      node_modules/gh-pages
  mini-css-extract-plugin  0.6.0 - 1.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
  node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
  postcss-normalize-url  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
    cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-declaration-sorter
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
    node_modules/cssnano-preset-default

postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-blank-pseudo/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-declaration-sorter/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-has-pseudo/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/cssnano-preset-default/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/icss-utils/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-browser-comments/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-calc/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-gray/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-colormin/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-convert-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-media/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-comments/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-empty/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-env-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-flexbugs-fixes/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-focus-visible/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-focus-within/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-font-variant/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-gap-properties/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-image-set-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-initial/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-lab-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-logical/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-media-minmax/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-params/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-scope/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-nesting/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-string/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-url/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-ordered-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-page-break/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-place/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-preset-env/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-selector-matches/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-selector-not/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-svgo/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/stylehacks/node_modules/postcss
  autoprefixer  9.0.0 - 9.8.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/autoprefixer
  css-blank-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-blank-pseudo
    postcss-preset-env  >=6.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-blank-pseudo
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-prefers-color-scheme
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-color-gray
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-double-position-gradients
    node_modules/postcss-preset-env
  css-declaration-sorter  4.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-declaration-sorter
    cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-declaration-sorter
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
    node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
  css-has-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-has-pseudo
  css-loader  2.0.0 - 4.3.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-loader
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
  css-prefers-color-scheme  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme
  cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano
    optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || 5.0.2 - 5.0.6
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
    node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
  cssnano-util-raw-cache  >=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache
  icss-utils  4.0.0 - 4.1.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/icss-utils
    postcss-modules-local-by-default  2.0.0 - 4.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default
    postcss-modules-values  2.0.0 - 4.0.0-rc.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/postcss-modules-values
  postcss-attribute-case-insensitive  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive
  postcss-browser-comments  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-browser-comments
    postcss-normalize  7.0.0 - 9.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-browser-comments
    node_modules/postcss-normalize
  postcss-calc  6.0.2 - 7.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-calc
  postcss-color-functional-notation  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation
  postcss-color-gray  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-gray
  postcss-color-hex-alpha  4.0.0 - 6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha
  postcss-color-mod-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function
  postcss-color-rebeccapurple  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple
  postcss-colormin  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-colormin
  postcss-convert-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-convert-values
  postcss-custom-media  7.0.0 - 7.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-media
  postcss-custom-properties  8.0.0 - 10.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-properties
  postcss-custom-selectors  5.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors
  postcss-dir-pseudo-class  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class
  postcss-discard-comments  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-comments
  postcss-discard-duplicates  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates
  postcss-discard-empty  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-empty
  postcss-discard-overridden  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden
  postcss-double-position-gradients  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients
  postcss-env-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-env-function
  postcss-flexbugs-fixes  4.0.0 - 4.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-flexbugs-fixes
  postcss-focus-visible  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-visible
  postcss-focus-within  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-within
  postcss-font-variant  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-font-variant
  postcss-gap-properties  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-gap-properties
  postcss-image-set-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-image-set-function
  postcss-initial  3.0.0 - 3.0.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-initial
  postcss-lab-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-lab-function
  postcss-loader  3.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-loader
  postcss-logical  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-logical
  postcss-media-minmax  4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-media-minmax
  postcss-merge-longhand  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.6 - 4.0.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand
  postcss-merge-rules  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-rules
  postcss-minify-font-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values
  postcss-minify-gradients  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients
  postcss-minify-params  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-params
  postcss-minify-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors
  postcss-modules-extract-imports  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports
  postcss-modules-scope  2.0.0 - 2.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-scope
  postcss-nesting  7.0.0 - 7.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-nesting
  postcss-normalize-charset  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset
  postcss-normalize-display-values  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values
  postcss-normalize-positions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
  postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
  postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
  postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
  postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
  postcss-normalize-url  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
  postcss-ordered-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
  postcss-overflow-shorthand  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  >=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-reduce-initial  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-selector-matches  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  postcss-svgo  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
  node_modules/postcss-svgo
  postcss-unique-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  resolve-url-loader  3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader
  stylehacks  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks
```

I've ran npm audit fix --force but it only halved the errors and to 46 and 15 of those are high. Any idea why this happens?

Here is my package.json in case its needed.

```
{
  "homepage": "http://dpsilvaa97.github.io/esf-zoomplus",
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.21.3",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "npm": "^7.14.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you create the project?

Comment: Im using webstorm but it uses create react app scipt

Comment: create-react-app might not be updated with the last versions.

Comment: how do i create without it though?

Comment: just run "run audit fix" to get the updates, or wait until they update the template

Comment: i did, as i said up there it fixes the low warning but gets even worse with high risk ones. In the end i get less but more high level ones

Comment: @jordiburgos npm audit fix doesn't work for me and I get the following "3 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated"

Comment: As the message says, "required manual review", you have to check those dependencies and investigate how to fix them specifically.

Answer (score 0):

These vulnerabilities are false positives according to the create-react-app team [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11054#issuecomment-873122155).

The discuss in detail in [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174) issue. The solution involves adding `react-scripts` to your dev dependencies and running `npm audit --production`